# Docassemble: "check in", background_response(), and "input type: combobox"

Tags: combobox, docassemble

I have been following [this example](https://docassemble.org/docs/background.html#background_response_target) to update a combobox of a list of states based on input into a country field. The states combobox updates correctly, but if the country field is also a `input type: combobox`, `background_response()` doesn't seem to fire, so the list of states isn't updated. I suspect this may have to do with the unique nature of comboboxes, where they *sort of* always have a value, but I'm not sure. `input type: radio`, and the default dropdown, work correctly in this scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug that was fixed in docassemble version 1.4.61.